# Adding shadow do image link when clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem adding styles to a clicked link - it's an image and I want it to have a shadow once it's clicked but I can't get that to happen, neither `shadow` nor `box-shadow` seem to do anything.

I managed to get it working on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4GgBe/

But it won't work on my page:

http://jovansfreelance.com/booklist/list/man/Best-Stand-Alone-Fantasy-Books

You can see the link when you lick the green '1 reranks' button (it's the one with the little colored bars on it). I even tried copying the entire CSS from the page to jsFiddle, and it still worked on jsFiddle but not on the page. Can someone spot the problem?

Comment: Hm, re-link is the big green link - the style would work for that one (checked just now) but I need it on the .shadow link, which is the one in the div that opens up after you click the green one.

Comment: Probably best adding a class to the button when it's clicked maybe using jQuery and the class will contain your shadow styles.

Comment: it works if i apply a class & put show on active(clicked) of that <a>

Comment: @SVS I meant .shower, not .shadow, sorry.

Comment: Its not applied anywhere in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The class on your link does not match your CSS. The class assigned to the link is "showeranks" but the CSS rule is assigned to "shower".

You just need to edit your live CSS to look like this:

```
a.showeranks:active{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px blue;
}
```